# How can I handle the promise rejection with a filter inside?

Tags: javascript, json, promise

So I'm trying to build an autocomplete searchbar to filter by name or id, data gets fetched from a JSON (data.json) with several pokemons.

Here is a part of the JSON:

```
{ 
    "1" :{"id": "1", "name": "bulbasaur"}, 
    "2" :{"id": "2", "name": "ivysaur"}, 
    "3" :{"id": "3", "name": "venusaur"}, 
    "4" :{"id": "4", "name": "charmander"}, 
    "5" :{"id": "5", "name": "charmeleon"}
}
```

and here is the JS code:

```
const search = document.querySelector('#search-bar');

const searchPokemon = async searchText => {
    const res = await fetch('./data.json')
    const pokemons = await res.json();  
    
    // Get matches
    let matches = pokemons.filter(pokemon => {
        const regexp = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        return pokemon.name.match(regexp) || pokemon.id.match(regexp);
    });
    console.log(matches);
}

search.addEventListener('input', () => searchPokemon(search.value));
```

I want to get the matches on the console but I get an Unhandled Promise Rejection error. I tried a try...catch but I still get errors. Anyone who can point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: wrap your async code in `try-catch`

Comment: Your `pokemons` object is **not an array**, it has no `filter()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Don't put the `console.log` effect inside of your `search` function, `return` the value instead -

```js
async function searchPokemon(searchText) {
  const res = await fetch('./data.json')
  const pokemons = await res.json()
  const regexp = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi')  

  if (pokemons == null)
    return []
  else
    return pokemons.filter(pokemon =>
      pokemon.name.match(regexp) || pokemon.id.match(regexp)
    )
}
```

Put the effect in your event listener. `console.log` or `searchResultElement.appendChild(...)` -

```js
const search = document.querySelector('#search-bar');

search.addEventListener('input', async event => {
  try {
    const pokemons = await searchPokemon(search.value)
    console.log("got pokemons", pokemons)
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error("An error occurred", err)
  }
})
```

Comment: And you should probably debounce the search so that it doesn't happen on every keystroke